# How to open an activity from a thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have 2 classes. At the end of the ConnectThread I want to open a new activity. This code I found on StackOverflow but it doensn't work. Can anyone tell me how to solve this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // some code

}



class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {  
        // some code
    }

    public void run() {  
        // some code

        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent startPostGet = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostGetActivity.class);                    
                startActivity(startPostGet);
            }
        });   
    }
}
```

Comment: how and where you use ConnectThread? It seems that ConnectThread has no context MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    Context context;
    public ConnectThread(Context context, BluetoothDevice device) {  
        this.context = context;
        // some code
    }

    public void run() {  
        // some code

        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent startPostGet = new Intent(context, PostGetActivity.class);                    
                context.startActivity(startPostGet);
            }
        });   
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if `context` is not an `Activity`, you need to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Answer (score 0):

I **think** (since you didn't tell us your error) that your problem is the `Context`. `startActivity` is a method of `Context`, but where you call `startActivity`, the scope is within `Runnable` or `ConnectThread` which doesn't have a method `startActivity`. If I'm right about that, then pass a `Context` to your thread and use `myContext.startActivity()`.

If that's not the problem, tell me what error you're getting and I'm sure I can help.

And you may need to use [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) depending upon the context (if it's not an `Activity` context.